# Python pandas dataframe ne method issue

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes like

here is the original data:
dataframe:1

```
 coverage_level_identifier data_status_code        last_change_date          last_change_user_name           creation_date             creation_user_name  minimum_coverage_level_percentage  erp_factor
0                          1                I 2022-05-10 07:37:49.997     28200310169021034302-Admin 2022-04-12 14:05:36.897                   Initial Load                               0.50       0.200
1                          2                A 2022-05-10 07:37:41.320     28200310169021034302-Admin 2022-04-12 14:05:36.897                   Initial Load                               0.55       0.250
2                          3                A 2022-05-09 16:14:58.997     28200310160021016916-Admin 2022-04-12 14:05:36.897                   Initial Load                               0.60       0.825
3                          4                A 2022-05-09 14:29:20.603     28200310169021034302-Admin 2022-04-12 14:05:36.897                   Initial Load                               0.65       0.850
```

dataframe 2:

```
   coverage_level_identifier data_status_code        last_change_date          last_change_user_name           creation_date             creation_user_name  minimum_coverage_level_percentage  erp_factor
0                          1                I 2022-05-10 07:37:49.997     28200310169021034302-Admin 2022-04-12 14:05:36.897                   Initial Load                               0.50       0.200
1                          2                A 2022-05-10 07:37:41.320     28200310169021034302-Admin 2022-04-12 14:05:36.897                   Initial Load                               0.55       0.250
2                          3                A 2022-05-09 16:14:58.997     28200310160021016916-Admin 2022-04-12 14:05:36.897                   Initial Load                               0.60       0.825
3                          4                A 2022-05-09 14:29:20.603     28200310169021034302-Admin 2022-04-12 14:05:36.897                   Initial Load                               0.65       0.850
```

this code returns

```
neDF=dataframe1.drop_duplicates(keep="first").reset_index(drop=True).ne(dataframe2.drop_duplicates(keep="first").reset_index(drop=True), axis=1)
```

neDF:

```
   coverage_level_identifier  data_status_code  last_change_date  last_change_user_name  creation_date  creation_user_name  minimum_coverage_level_percentage  erp_factor
0                      False             False             False                  False          False               False                              False       False
1                      False             False             False                  False          False               False                              False       False
2                      False             False             False                  False          False               False                              False        True
3                      False             False             False                  False          False               False                              False       False
```

why is there a TRUE in erp_factor column after "ne" ?, not sure where anything is wrong, Please advice

Comment: i get False for all of them, have a look at the actual data, or floating point precision for the factor column

Comment: Return False for every row. Share the original data.

Comment: @Nehal shared original data

Comment: @sammywemmy I see them as float64 datatypes in both data frames.fyi.

Comment: @Bill I am still getting False for every single one of them. Are the `dtypes` for both the columns same?